# How to use the five type of data structure in redis perfectly

Tags: php, caching, redis

As the title saying,i have experience in using "string" structure as cache and using list structure as queue.But,there are also have three types:hash,set and order set in redis.So,what situation of this three types supposed to?
Expect your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Think of hash set and ordered set as distributed versions of the same data types, names [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)).

You could use the set to count the total number of unique instances of X across multiple services without worrying about communication issues, or since redis itself is a key value store, you can take advantage of this and think of the whole thing as a 2 layer hash table.

I myself mainly like redis for making it really easy to communicate data between services and keeping them in sync in certain scenarios